# GROUP values separated by specific records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to make a specific counter which will raise by one after a specific record is found in a row.

```
  time    event      revenue   counter

 13.37    START        20          1  
 13.38   action A      10          1  
 13.40   action B       5          1  
 13.42      end                    1  

 14.15    START        20          2  
 14.16   action B       5          2  
 14.18     end                     2  

 15.10    START        20          3  
 15.12     end                     3
```

I need to find out total revenue for every visit (actions between START and END). I was thinking the best way would be to set a counter like this:

so I could group events. But if you have a better solution, I would be grateful.

Comment: Are you using MySql or SQL Server?  MySql allows in-line assignments.

Comment: Im using SQL server btw

Comment: Please post the **expected result** for this data sample. Are you allowed to add such counter as an additional field to your table or do you plan to build it "on the fly" in your SQL code?

Comment: Please remove your `MySql` tag then.

Comment: Tag removed. Unfortunately I am not allowed to edit table so I am lef with "on the fly" option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query similar to the following:

```
with StartTimes as
(
  select time,
    startRank = row_number() over (order by time)
  from events
  where event = 'START'
)
select e.*, counter = st.startRank
from events e
  outer apply
  (
    select top 1 st.startRank
    from StartTimes st
    where e.time >= st.time
    order by st.time desc
  ) st
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/254e4/5).

May need to be updated based on the particular characteristics of the actual data, things like duplicate times, missing events, etc. But it works for the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012 supports an OVER clause for aggregates, so if you're up to date on version, this will give you the counter you want:

```
count(case when eventname='START' then 1 end) over (order by eventtime)
```

You could also use the latest START time instead of a counter to group by, like this:

```
with t as (
  select
  *,
  max(case when eventname='START' then eventtime end)
    over (order by eventtime) as timeStart
  from YourTable
)
  select
    timeStart,
    max(eventtime) as timeEnd,
    sum(revenue) as totalRevenue
  from t
  group by timeStart;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/254e4/6)'s a SQL Fiddle demo using the schema Ian posted for his solution.